# Disable unbound amount of fields with JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with lets say 50 checkboxes. And i want to disable them on form load, i do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#check").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

but this only disables the first checkbox. All checkboxes got the `id='check'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkboxes need to have unique ID, ID = unique identifier.
Instead use classes:

add class `check` to each checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".check").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, all answers all correct, but i must accept the fastest. :)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML every `id` attribute should be unique, try adding classes for your checkboxes and select them with that class, or just use attribute selectors like `$('input[type=checkbox]')`

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique you may try with the class name like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".classname").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`id`s are unique and therefore cannot be shared among elements. If you are grouping many elements together, use a `class` instead:

**HTML**:

```
<input class="check" ...>
<input class="check" ...>
<input class="check" ...>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.check').prop('disabled', true);
});
```